# Prove that $T(V_0)= \{ T(v):v \in V_0 \}$ is a subspace of $W$ and that $dim(V_0)=dim(T(V_0))$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:V \rightarrow W$ be invertible. Let $V_0$ be a subspace of $V$.  Prove that $T(V_0)= \{ T(v):v \in V_0 \}$ is a subspace of $W$ and that $dim(V_0)=dim(T(V_0))$.

1. Suppose that $\{v_1, v_2, ..., v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$.  Then $\{T(v_1), T(v_2), ...,T(v_n)\}$ spans $W$.  Then we just take a subset of the basis for $V$ and show that the linear transformation on that is a subset of the original set and so it's span is a subset of the original span, and so $T(V_0)$ is a subspace of $W$.
2. Once we prove that $T(V_0)= \{ T(v):v \in V_0 \}$ is a subspace of $W$, I'm not sure how to prove that $dim(V_0)=dim(T(V_0))$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Consider the restriction of $T$ to domain $V_0$ and codomain $T(V_0)$. Actually $T$ doesn't even have to be invertible: it is enough it be injective.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Could you explain a little bit more on why $dim(V_0)=dim(T(V_0))$?

Comment: $V_0$  and $T(V_0)$ are isomorphic. Actually, if you know some group theory, it results from the 1st isomorphism theorem (which you don't need here).